# Project intersection of a cylinder and a cone?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I'm given $x^2+y^2=4$ and $z^2=x^2+y^2$ and I need to find the volume between them two (I assume cylindrical coordinates will be the best choice here).

I get what the surface looks like, since it's pretty simple to visualize. However, I'm not sure how to project on the $xy$, $zy$, $xz$ planes.

Not sure, but I suppose I have to find the intersection between the cone and the cylinder and for that my gut instinct is to set both equations equal to each other. However, I don't know if this is correct: $z^2=4$. So that would mean they intersect when $z=-2$ and $z=2$?

If that is true, then the projection on $xy$ would be a circle of radius 2. But what about the $zy$ and $xz$ planes?

Comment: So how can I set up the cylindrical coordinates in this case? I can see that the radius goes all around the circle so $0 \le \theta \le 2 \pi$ and the height is $-2 \le z \le 2$. But the radius goes from the cone to the cylinder. How do I write that to get the bounds of $r$?

Comment: You have $z^2=r^2 \implies z=\pm r$ so the bounds for $z$ are actually from $-r$ to $r$. The use $x^2+y^2=4$ to find the other bounds because this is the shadow onto the $xy$ plane. It is true that they intersect when $z=-2$ and $z=2$  but that is irrelevant as $z$ actually depends on $r$.

Comment: So the integral would end up like this? $\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^2 \int_{-r}^r dz dr d\theta$ Is this correct?

Comment: You forgot the Jacobian $r$, but otherwise that would be correct.

Comment: Darn! The Jacobian is my karma. Thank you!!